# How to prove that sequence is divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have a certain sequence 
$$a_n= \frac{(-1)^n n^3}{n^3+2n^2+1} .$$
I know this sequence is divergent, but I do not know how to prove it. I tried using a theorem that says: 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0.$$
But he says nothing if $ \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = L$ (in this case $L= 1$).
So I would like to know how you proved that sequence is divergent.

Comment: Check $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n + 1}$ and use the fact that for a sequence to have a limit all it's subsequences must have the same limit.

Comment: Consider subsequences of even and odd  terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^3}}.$$
I think now it's clear.

Comment: Yes ... But in this case the $ \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n| = 1$ but the theorem says nothing when the $ \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n| = 1$

Comment: @Matheus $a_{2k}\rightarrow1$ and $a_{2k-1}\rightarrow-1$. Thus, $a$ is divergent. Let $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=L$. Thus, for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $|a_n-L|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for some natural $n$. It's a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider it when $n$ is odd and $n$ is even separately!